# jQuery help with condensing multiple consecutive .animate() functions

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm in the process of developing a business advert with a number of consecutive elements which all implement jQuery UI's `.animate()` function on page load.

For the sake of compelling jQuery to run more efficiently, I've been attempting to condense the below script into one function but can't seem to do so without jQuery running every `.animate()` function simultaneously instead of consecutively with increments.

If you want to check out my [test site](http://testsite00.hostoi.com) to see what I'm aiming for, I am trying to animate each li class on the left in increments starting with 'Services', ending with 'Home' but jQuery seems to be allergic to my previous attempts.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

jQuery:

```
//li classes 
    $('.home').hide();
    $('.home:hidden').delay(650).animate({top:"0"}, 1).show(650);
    $('.home').animate({top:"58"}, 600)

    $('.about').hide(); 
    $('.about:hidden').delay(500).animate({top:"58"}, 1).show(500);
    $('.about').animate({top:"142"}, 600);

    $('.contact').hide();
    $('.contact:hidden').delay(350).animate({top:"142"}, 1).show(350);
    $('.contact').animate({top:"226"}, 600);

    $('.services').hide();
    $('.services:hidden').delay(200).animate({top:"226"}, 1).show(200);
    $('.services').animate({top:"310"}, 600);

//dividers 
    $('#divider_home').hide()
    $('#divider_home').delay(1600).show(650); 

    $('#divider_about').hide()
    $('#divider_about').delay(1800).show(600); 

    $('#divider_contact').hide()
    $('#divider_contact').delay(2000).show(600); 

    $('#divider_services').hide()
    $('#divider_services').delay(2200).show(600);
```

Comment: If it isn't possible with jQuery, would someone be able to point me in the rite direction of maybe a plugin that could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then this code may help:

```
var liTops = [ 0, 58, 142, 226, 310 ];
var liDelays = [ 650, 500, 350, 200 ];
$( '#thumb' ).children( 'ul' ).find( 'li' ).each( function( i ) { 
    $( this ).hide().delay( liDelays[i] ).animate( { top: liTops[i] }, 1 ).show( liDelays[i] ).animate( { top:liTops[i + 1] }, 600);
} );

var dividerDelays = [ 1600, 1800, 2000, 2200 ];
$( '#left_nav' ).children( 'div[id^="divider_"]' ).each( function( i ) {
    $( this ).hide().delay( dividerDelays[i] ).show( 600 );
} );
```

Comment: Not only did it help, it thoroughly did what I wanted it to.. I suddenly feel foolish lol.  I updated the site in my OP if you want to check it out.  Thanks :o)